# loading data in dropdownlists in popup in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, modalpopup

I am new to asp.net mvc.
i am able to show pop-ups in mvc.
http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/42R0171112-CRUD-Operations-using-jQuery-dialog-and-Entity-Framework---MVC-Razor.html

I am able to load data in dropdownlist in mvc.
but, i want to load data in dropdownlist which exist inside a pop-up so how to do that.

or i have to load data in dropdownlist before showing it but that will not be best way as user may or may not show popup.

please suggest.

Comment: Once ur pop up is loaded, u can make an Ajax request, which will return JSON, and then u can bind the dropdown with that JSON.... Let me know if u want any more description abt it..

Comment: thanks for your direction, please post your description, it will more helpful

Comment: How are you showing the PopUp? modal pop up??

Comment: See my answer here for another way to load data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21534325/bind-drop-down-list-inside-cshtm-with-server-side-data/21534611#21534611

Comment: @donstack - If this has worked for you, then pls mark it as answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function openPopUp()
{
  // ur code to open the popup
   LoadDropDownContent(); 
}
function LoadDropDownContent()
{
     var url = $(this).data('url')// url of ur ActionResult;
        var data = //Any data u want to pass on 
        //get the timestamp
        var nocache = new Date().getTime();
        //add the timestamp as a paramter to avoid caching
        data['nocache'] = nocache;
        $.getJSON(url, data, function (items) {
            var ddl = $('#urdrpdownid');
            ddl.empty();
            ddl.append($('<option/>', { value: '', text: '--Selecteer--' }));
            $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                ddl.append($('<option/>', {
                    value: item.Value,
                    text: item.Text,
                    selected: item.Selected
                }));
            });
        }); 
}
```

Code in your Controller

```
public ActionResult GetItems()
{
     var dropdownitems = //ur BL/DAL function to retrieve the list of entity;
     var items = dropdownitems.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.ColName, Value = s.ColName}).AsEnumerable();
        return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```